# Why does an indexed slice query seem to take random but consistent times to load data?

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

I get bug reports all the time from testers complaining that my page is not loading data from cassandra fast enough. The data loads anything with a timestamp that is in between the current day and 30 days prior to it, along with any other filter criterion the user enters, including how many data points to load per page (I implemented some code that retrieves data one "page" at a time from cassandra so as to avoid memory issues from loading hundreds of thousands of data points at once).

On some days, loading the maximum number per page takes less than a second, and on others, it takes 15 minutes. On any given day the length of time it takes to load is consistent, but the next day the loading time can change drastically from the day before.

What possible causes can there be for this? I'd like to be able to give a definitive answer to my supervisor and to the testers so that I can stop sending back the bug reports with no fix or explanation.

The Java API I use to retrieve data from Cassandra is Hector, currently version 1.0-5

If you require more information I will try my best to accomodate. Thank you to anyone who can help.

Comment: Alright instead of asking for more information my question was simply voted down as unclear or showing lack of research. I can assure you I've been beating this dead horse for about 3 weeks and will gladly share any information I am asked for beyond what is written above. Please ask questions if anythign needs clarification or expanding upon!

Comment: I can add a few theories I've had, though I don't know how credible they are:

1. Traffic - I've considered that maybe a lot of people might be requesting data at once, but have more or less shot that down because there is only one tester, so I can't imagine any reason why there'd be a lot of traffic in the testing environment

2. Data size - Cassandra seems to have more trouble retrieving small data pools when given a large maximum number of points to load. I've been wondering if expectation has an impact.

Comment: I should have asked before sharing an answer but : can you give us how many secondary indexes you have and the different values they can take? Also how much customization you need. Examples of what you do would be a huge help to make my answer more useful.

Answer (score 2):

The performances of secondary indexes in Cassandra are heavily dependent of the number of different values that indexed column has.

Like is said in this documnetation : http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/ddl/indexes
An enum would be good candidate for secondary indexes. But searching a row by an arbitrary secondary unique key will get slower and slower as your data grow. (in short Country code: yes; emails: no)

If you have a lot of those indexed columns that would be in common with few other rows (like emails, street address, phone numbers, ...) I would suggest creating another row with those indexes as keys (same column family or different one) and copy the row content in there too. Denormalization is something you should think of in cassandra.

I would also advise to eliminate everything that is older than a certain timestamp using TTL or by filtering it on your side rather than adding an extra condition in your query.